# row_number partition result wrong

Tags: sql, window-functions

I am using ROW_NUMBER to rank countries by sales desc. Query looks like below

```
SELECT country, SUM(sales) AS sales,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY SUM(sales) DESC) AS 'rank'
FROM table
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY sales DESC
```

For some reason the rank is one for all the countries.

Comment: because you are grouping by country and also partitioning by country you will always get 1 row per country with a rank of 1. remove `partition by country` from `row_number`.

Comment: `AS 'rank'` is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you partition by `COUNTRY`, the row_number reset to 1

```
SELECT country, 
       SUM(sales) AS sales, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sales) DESC) AS 'rank'
FROM table
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY sales DESC
```

Comment: Ah yes, didnt think about that.

Comment: You can also use SUM window function and eliminate the group by.

Comment: @JoeC I tought about it, but then will you be able to add the `row_number`?